# DRY principle in signals

Tags: django

**Django 1.11.1**

Below are signal handlers. This is about saving history.
That is difference is signal (post_save and post-delete) and operation(+ or -).

The code is mostly duplicated. Could you help me understand how can I adhere to DRY principle here?

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=FramePlace)
def save_add_place(sender,  **kwargs):

    current_request = CrequestMiddleware.get_request()
    author = current_request.user

    instance = kwargs.get('instance')
    frame = instance.frame
    place = instance.place


    FramePlaceHistory.objects.create(author=author,
                                     operation="+",
                                     frame=frame,
                                     place=place)


@receiver(post_delete, sender=FramePlace)
def save_delete_place(sender,  **kwargs):

    current_request = CrequestMiddleware.get_request()
    author = current_request.user

    instance = kwargs.get('instance')
    frame = instance.frame
    place = instance.place


    FramePlaceHistory.objects.create(author=author,
                                     operation="-",
                                     frame=frame,
                                     place=place)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put you code in a function, it keeps the code simple (KISS) and you don't repeat yourself

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=FramePlace)
def save_add_place(sender, **kwargs):
    create_frame("+", kwargs)

@receiver(post_delete, sender=FramePlace)
def save_delete_place(sender, **kwargs):
    create_frame("-", kwargs)

def create_frame(operation, kwargs)
    current_request = CrequestMiddleware.get_request()
    author = current_request.user

    instance = kwargs.get('instance')
    frame = instance.frame
    place = instance.place


    FramePlaceHistory.objects.create(
        author=author,
        operation=operation,
        frame=frame,
        place=place
    )
```